# Determine if $T: \mathcal{P}_2 \rightarrow M_{2\times 2}$ is onto/one to one with $T(a + bx + cx^2) = \begin{bmatrix}a+b&a+2c\\2a+c&b-c\end{bmatrix}$

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, linear-transformations

> Determine if $T: \mathcal{P}_2 \rightarrow M_{2\times 2}$ is onto/one to one with $T(a + bx + cx^2) = \begin{bmatrix}a+b&a+2c\\2a+c&b-c\end{bmatrix}$

I believe that $\ker T = \{ \mathbb{0} \}$, which follows from:

$\begin{bmatrix}a+b&a+2c\\2a+c&b-c\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$

$\Rightarrow b = c, a = -b$

$2a + c = a + 2c \Rightarrow a = c$

So we have $a = b = c$ and $a = -b$ so $a = 0 = b = c$

Thus $T$ is one to one.

From the rank theorem, and knowing $\dim\mathcal{P}_2 = 3$, we know that $\operatorname{rank} T = 3$.

I'm not sure where to go from here. I'm fairly sure there will be a theorem that I'm missing which prove surjectivity.

Comment: You should be solving that equation! For which $a, b, c$ do we have$$\begin{bmatrix}a+b&a+2c\\2a+c&b-c\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}?$$If you find non-zero solutions, then $T$ is not one-to-one.

Comment: There might be a flaw in my working, but edited to show thought process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It cannot be surjective. In fact, every linear map $L:\mathcal P_2\to M_2(\Bbb R)$ cannot be surjective.

Because for First Isomorphism Theorem, $\dim\ker L+\dim\text{Im} L=\dim\mathcal P_2=3$, so $\dim\text{Im} L\le3$. but $\dim M_2(\Bbb R)=4$, so $\text{Im}L\ne M_2(\Bbb R)$.

Your proof about injectivity is flawless.

Comment: Once we know this map is not surjective it is quick to find some specific $2 \times 2$ matrices that are not mapped to under this mapping.  For example, the matrix of all 1's is not mapped to.  As another example, the matrix with 0's on the diagonal and 1's off diagonal is not mapped to.